# How do I get the memory usage of a thread in C? (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, memory

I am trying to limit the time and memory usage by multithreading the `thread1` thread and a limit thread. The limit thread is (supposed to be) a while loop that calculates the memory every time, and if it exceeds the limit, it will signal an error for exceeding the limits. The time is limited with `WaitForSingleObject` function.
The problem is that it keeps returning the error code 6 when I try to measure the memory usage. I use the method `GetProcessMemoryInfo`, but that simply returns 0; i.e. it did not work. That results the measure to be some large negative value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <time.h>

struct global_vars {
    clock_t started_at;
    int time_complex;
    double memory_complex;
};

DWORD WINAPI sleeper(LPVOID param) {
    int x[5000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        x[i] = 5000;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    DWORD thread1id;
    HANDLE thread1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, sleeper, NULL, 0, &thread1id);
    
    printf("%d\n", thread1id);
    if (thread1) {
        PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
        WaitForSingleObject(thread1, INFINITE);
        /*
        int out = 4;
        if (GetExitCodeThread(thread1, &out) == STILL_ACTIVE) {
            printf("TIME OUT!");
            TerminateThread(thread1, -1);
        }*/
        GetProcessMemoryInfo(thread1, &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
        printf("\tPageFaultCount: %d\n", pmc.PageFaultCount);
        printf("\tPeakWorkingSetSize: %d\n",
            pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize);
        printf("\tWorkingSetSize: %d\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize);
        printf("\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: %d\n",
            pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage);
        printf("\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: %d\n",
            pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage);
        printf("\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: %d\n",
            pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage);
        printf("\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: %d\n",
            pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage);
        printf("\tPagefileUsage: %d\n", pmc.PagefileUsage);
        printf("\tPeakPagefileUsage: %d\n",
            pmc.PeakPagefileUsage);
        printf("%s", strerror(GetLastError()));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to limit memory usage on the second parameter of CreateThread, but it did not work as expected. I tried to get the difference of the main function and after using the thread, but that was not too accurate (5k+ bytes error).

Comment: You need to set `pmc.cb = sizeof(pmc);` prior to calling `GetProcessMemoryInfo`  Also, GetProcessMemoryInfo expects a handle to a process, not a thread.

Comment: You are asking the impossible. Processes have memory. Threads have execution streams.

Comment: So that means that all the memory from the thread is stored on the main process? (GetCurrentProcess())

Comment: If you want to limit the amount of heap used by the thread, then you'll probably need to create your own allocation manager and use that for everything on the thread that uses dynamic memory. That'll give you the most control, and should be reasonably accurate, provided you use that exclusively. But if you're essentially wrapping `malloc` and `free` you still won't have a full picture of the thread's overhead because memory management is complicated. If you go too deep down this rabbit hole, you'll regret it. Separately, you _can_ specify the stack size for a thread in Windows.

Comment: Maybe a better solution would be to pre-allocate a memory block as large as the limit and let the thread use that. And use static arrays as much as you can. Now instead of having to monitor the thread, you simply know it's only using what you've limited it to.